# CloudKit -How to Cancel a Save/Upload Operation that's in Progress

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Is there a way to cancel a CloudKit save or upload operation that's in progress?

This isn't a `time-out` situation. I notice videos take some time to upload and the user might decide to dismiss the vc. I would like to cancel the current upload if they do that.

```
let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

var operation: CKModifyRecordsOperation?

func save(videoURL: URL) {

    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "MyType")
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoURL.path)
    let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: fileURL)
    record["videoAsset"] = asset

    database.save(record) { (record, err) in
    }

    // or

    operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [record], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
    operation?.savePolicy = .allKeys
    operation?.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (savedRecordIDs, deletedRecordsIDs, error) in
    }

    database.add(operation!)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a reference to `CKModifyRecordsOperation`, you can call `cancel`.

```
operation?.cancel()
```

If you look up the doc for `CKModifyRecordsOperation`, it says the following.

> If you assign a completion handler to the completionBlock property of
> the operation, CloudKit calls it after the operation executes and
> returns the results. Use the completion handler to perform any
> housekeeping tasks for the operation, but don’t use it to process the
> results of the operation. The completion handler you provide should
> manage any failures of the operation, whether due to an error or an
> explicit cancellation.

Comment: Thanks, I just found *The completion handler you provide should manage any failures of the operation, whether due to an error or an explicit cancellation.* as a comment on a different post and I was just about to start looking into it.